# mysql nested query with max value

Tags: mysql, nested

I have three tables as follows and am trying to extract the number of times a questionnaire has been provided for the highest visit_number for a member. The idea is to prevent a questionnaire being prompted to the visitor if it has already been prompted twice recently (visit_number field as incremented once certain amount of time has elapsed). My bash at it is as follows (below tables) but this clearly isn't right and I get thousands of results. Hopefully you'll at least be able to see what i'm trying to do with it

```
Members
->id

Visits
->id
->visit_number
->member_id

Questionnaire
->id
->visit_id

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM questionnaires q
JOIN visits v 
ON q.visit_id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM visits v WHERE v.member_id = ".$this->id.")
ORDER BY q.id DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM questionnaires q
INNER JOIN Visits v1 ON q.visit_id = v1.id
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT MAX(visit_number) MaxVisitNumber, member_id
    FROM visits
    GROUP BY member_id
) v2 ON v1.member_id = v2.member_id AND v1.visit_number = v2.MaxVisitNumber
INNER JOIN members m ON v2.member_id = m.Id
WHERE m.Id = @someId
```

Comment: Thanks. Assuming should be `MAX(visit_number) AS MaxVisitNumber` and `visits v2 on v1.id`, i am getting a syntax error `near 'v2 ON v1.id = v2.id` - just trying to figure out what's going on.

Comment: @bsod99 - Sorry It is `member_id` instead of `id` like `ON v1.member_id = v2.member_id` see my edit.